# waiting for the page to load nonangular site

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

my tests are working ...sort of...
the issue is that some times this finds the elements and sometime it doesn't. I am assuming that the page is loading a little later. I need to add some kind of wait time. I am not sure how would that work with non-angular site

here is the part that works...hmm about 50% of the time

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log In']")).submit();
```

here is what I tried to do

```
        browser.driver.wait(function() {
            expect(browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log In']"))).isPresent().toBe(true);
        });
        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Log In']")).submit();
```

here is the stack that I get

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
The last active task was: 
WebDriver.sleep(50000)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.timeout (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1358:15)
    at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.sleep (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:600:21)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/craiglist.js:56:24)
    at /Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd/index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1640:20)
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1505:8)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
F

Failures:

  1) Craigslist automation should greet the named user
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 11.073 seconds
1 test, 2 assertions, 1 failure

Asims-MacBook-Air:test asimzaidi$ ./node_modules/.bin/protractor  protractor.conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
F

Failures:

  1) Craigslist automation should greet the named user
   Message:
     Error: expect called with WebElement argument, expected a Promise. Did you mean to use .getText()?
   Stacktrace:
     Error: expect called with WebElement argument, expected a Promise. Did you mean to use .getText()?
    at Error (<anonymous>)
==== async task ====
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/mytest.js:56:24)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/craiglist.js:13:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/mytest.js:10:1)

Finished in 9.707 seconds
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem while testing. I had to figure out an optimum wait time for the tests by running the tests multiple times. Also, I increased the timeout interval for the specs:
 jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 20000}
Hope this helps you!

Comment: are you ignoring browser synchronization? `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`